# How can I schedule the invalidation of a redis cache?

Tags: django, content-management-system, redis, django-cache, redis-cache

I am using django as a framework to build a content management system for a site with a blog.

Each blog post will have a route that contains a unique identifier for the blog post. These blog posts can be scheduled and have an expiry date. This means that the routes have to be dynamic.

The entire site needs to be cached and we have redis set up as a back end cache. We currently cache rendered pages against out static routes, but need to find a way of caching pages against the dynamic routes (and invalidating them when the blog posts expire.)

I could use a cron job but it isn't appropriate because...
    a) New blog posts go live rarely and not periodically
    b) Users can schedule posts to the minute. This means that a cron job would have to run every minute which seems like overkill!

I've just found the [django-cacheops](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/cacheops/) library, which seems to do exactly what I need (schedule the invalidation of our cache and invalidate them via signals). Is this compatible with our existing setup and how easy is the setup?

I assume this is a pretty common problem - does anyone have any better ideas than the above?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on django-cacheops because I've never used it, but Redis provides a really easy way to do this using the [EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire) command:

> Set a timeout on key. After the timeout has expired, the key will automatically be deleted.

Usage:

```
SET some_key "some_value"
EXPIRE some_key 10
```

The key some_key will now automatically be cleaned/deleted by Redis in 10 seconds. If you need to delete blog posts' cache knowing when they should be deleted from the outset, this should serve your needs perfectly.

Comment: is it possible to cancel or change the expiry if, say, the user modified when the blog should expire?

Comment: Yeah, any time you rerun EXPIRE it updates the expire value on the key to the new one you're setting and completely overwrites the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Cacheops invalidate cache when a post is changed, that's its primary use. But you can also expire by timeout:

```
from cacheops import cached_as, cached_view_as

# A queryset
post = Post.objects.cache(timeout=your_timeout).get(pk=post_pk)

# A function
@cached_as(Post.objects.filter(pk=post_pk), timeout=your_timeout)
def get_post_data(...):
    ...

# A view
@cached_view_as(Post, timeout=your_timeout)
def post(request, ...):
    ...
```

However, there is currently no way you can specify timeout depending on cached object.